# How to read status code from response body of c# webclient request

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest, webclient.uploaddata

I am uploading data to my third party API and getting a `byte[]` as response. I need to read the status code from my response body as to if I am getting status code as 200 or not or if it was successfully uploaded or not.
 Any suggestions.

Code snippet.

```
var response = webClient.UploadData(postURL, "POST", formData);
```

response is coming as a `byte[]`. 
On using, `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resp);` I simply get all the data in string format.

Comment: Status code can be found in the head of a response not the body...

Comment: then how do i confirm whether the data i am posting to the url has been successfully uploaded or not?

Comment: hey thanks Eric...got my answer in the post above mentioned by you.